# Specific String Extraction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

How to extract only `Fencing` from `Abbotsford -Val Bldg - Fencing`, I have a table with a column of different values,I need to extract words after  `Val Bldg -`.
Kindly assist, as the length of different values is unknown.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do it:

```
DECLARE @S varchar(100) = 'Abbotsford -Val Bldg - Fencing'

SELECT  STUFF(@S, 1, PATINDEX('%Val Bldg -%', @S) + 10, '') As [Stuff],
        SUBSTRING(@S, PATINDEX('%Val Bldg -%', @S) + 11, LEN(@S)) As [Substring]
```

Results:

```
Stuff       Substring
Fencing     Fencing
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , As I am new to SQL Server 2016.Could you please tell me how can I apply this to a column as here we are onlydeclaring one specific value "'Abbotsford -Val Bldg - Fencing" ,how to try for different values in the column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help:-) I also tried this below query and it worked too...select SUBSTRING (substring(I.[column name],
    CHARINDEX('Bldg ',I.[column name]),
    len(I.[column name])),
    7,
       len(I.[column name])) as Item_Name from table;

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)